# How to display a list of ints and display total cost

Tags: java

This is my current code:

```
public static void Costs(float[] args) {

        Scanner Costs = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Item1Cost;
        System.out.print("Enter the cost of Item 1 £");
        Item1Cost = Costs.next(); 

        String Item2Cost;
        System.out.print("Enter the cost of Item 2 £");
        Item2Cost = Costs.next(); 

        String TotalCost;
        TotalCost = Item1Cost + ", " + Item2Cost;

        System.out.println("The cost of each of your items in order is: " + TotalCost);

    }
```

I am trying to change it so that it obtains an int form the user and displays all the prices, and also totals them.

When trying my self I used this, and I could get the 'costs' stored them in a string and display them but I can not make a total with this code. I was wondering if someone could give me a hand. I'm sure the answer is pretty simple, but I'm fairly new to java and I just cant think of a solution.

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions; i.e. variable names should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: in that case why dont you accept integer only using `Costs.nextInt()`

Answer (score 4):

So what you're doing at the moment is `String` concatenation. This is where you simply stick two `String` objects on the end of one another, and create a new `String` from that. This happens because, in Java the `+` operator is *overloaded*. This means that it expresses different functionality depending on the type of the operands.

**Example of overloaded operator**

```
String str = "Hello ";
String str2 = "World.";

String sentence = str + str2; // Sentence equals "Hello World."

int num1 = 5;
int num2 = 7;

int total = num1 + num2; // Same operator, but total equals 12, not 57.
```

---

What you need to do in your example is cast the operands to the correct types, so that Java knows how to work on them. That is, it overloads `+` to the correct functionality.

**Example**

```
int item1Cost = costs.nextInt(); //Notice the java naming conventions.
int item2Cost = costs.nextInt();

System.out.println("Total cost: " + (item1Cost + item2Cost));
```

Or you can pull the value in as a `String` and perform some validation. This is a safer option because it means you can control program flow easier.

```
String item1CostStr = costs.nextLine();
int item1Cost = 0;

if(item1CostStr.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    item1Cost = Integer.parseInt(item1CostStr);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was trying for a while to get that to work but constantly getting an incompatibility error, I didn't know how to fix. Thanks man, i feel dumb.

Comment: No problem man. Be sure to read the edit about overloaded operators, if you want to understand what's going on behind the scenes :)

Comment: Since its a price, int isnt really working, so would I be able to use float, or is there a better variable type for the price of things?

Comment: You should read in the value as a `String`, then use `NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` and use `format(String input)` method. Never use `double` or `float` to represent currency.

Answer (score 1):

to convert an string to an int and operate with it, you should use this method:

```
Integer.parseInt(string);
```

That method returns an `int`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input as an integer, use `scan.nextInt()` instead. Then it should work just fine.

This is a weird line of code though:

```
TotalCost = Item1Cost + ", " + Item2Cost;
```

What is it supposed to do? This won't compile if you're using integers.

Sidenote: use the java naming conventions. Variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: That was me making do, i've only recently started java and im not really sure with a lot of the syntax, but thanks.